# Amazon's IVS Player implementation for Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, amazon-ivs

Im trying to do a basic implementation of IVS player for flutter given that it seems to be the lowest latency player for streaming. There seems to be a flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/ivs_player but it lacks documentation or even a github repositry, plus the example is not very telling, I couldn't make it work, if anybody has a working example I will greatly appreciate that you share it.

I tried to create a plugin base on the native implementation from the Amazon's IVS Player SDK, I hear the audio but I don't see the video.

IVSPlayerManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import AmazonIVSPlayer

class IVSPlayerManager {
    var player: IVSPlayer!

    init() {
        player = IVSPlayer()
    }

    func play(url: String) {
        guard let streamURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
        player.load(streamURL)
        player.play()
    }

     func dispose() {
        player.pause()
        player = nil
    }

    // Other necessary functions
}
```

IVSPlayerViewFactory.swift

```
import Foundation
import Flutter
import UIKit
import AmazonIVSPlayer

class IVSPlayerViewFactory: NSObject, FlutterPlatformViewFactory {
    func create(withFrame frame: CGRect, viewIdentifier viewId: Int64, arguments args: Any?) -> FlutterPlatformView {
        return IVSPlayerFlutterView(frame: frame, viewId: viewId, args: args)
    }
}
```

IVSPlayerView.swift

```
import UIKit
import AmazonIVSPlayer
import Flutter

class IVSPlayerFlutterView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    private var player: IVSPlayer
    private var ivsPlayerView: IVSPlayerView

    init(frame: CGRect, viewId: Int64, args: Any?) {
        self.player = IVSPlayer()
        self.ivsPlayerView = IVSPlayerView(frame: frame)
        super.init()
        self.ivsPlayerView.player = player
        setupPlayer()
    }

    func view() -> UIView {
        return ivsPlayerView
    }

    private func setupPlayer() {
        // Load and play the stream URL as needed
        if let url = URL(string: "Streaming URL") {
            player.load(url)
        }
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import flutter_local_notifications
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    var ivsPlayerManager: IVSPlayerManager?

    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        // Register plugins with the Flutter framework
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { (registry) in
            GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: registry)
        }
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        // Set up the Flutter view controller
        let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController

        // Set up the flavor channel
        let flavorChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "flavor", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        flavorChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            let flavor = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["Flavor"] as? String
            result(flavor)
        })

        // Set up notification center delegate for iOS 10.0+
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        }

        // Initialize IVS Player Manager
        ivsPlayerManager = IVSPlayerManager()

        // Set up the IVS channel
        let ivsChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.ivs_player", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        ivsChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            if call.method == "play", let args = call.arguments as? [String: Any], let url = args["url"] as? String {
                self.ivsPlayerManager?.play(url: url)
            }
            else if call.method == "dispose" {
                // Dispose logic for the player
                self.ivsPlayerManager?.dispose()
                }
             else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
        }

        // Register IVS Player View Factory
        let registrar = self.registrar(forPlugin: "plugin-name")
        registrar?.register(IVSPlayerViewFactory(), withId: "ivs_player_view")

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

And this is the flutter part:

```
class IvsVideoPlayer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 300, // Example height
      width: 300, // Example width
      child: Platform.isIOS ? UiKitView(
        viewType: 'ivs_player_view',
        onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
      ) : AndroidView(
        viewType: 'ivs_player_view',
        onPlatformViewCreated: _onPlatformViewCreated,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onPlatformViewCreated(int id) {
    // Platform view created logic
  }
}
```

IVSPlayerController.dart

```
class IvsPlayerController {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('com.example.ivs_player');

  Future<void> play(String url) async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('play', {'url': url});
  }

    Future<void> dispose() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('dispose');
  }
}
```

And this an example on how I'm using the plugin:

```
class VideoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoScreenState createState() => _VideoScreenState();
}

class _VideoScreenState extends State<VideoScreen> {
    final IvsPlayerController _ivsController = IvsPlayerController();



 @override
void dispose() {
  _ivsController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _ivsController.play('Streaming_URL.m3u8');
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: 
     IvsVideoPlayer()
    );
  }}
```